# Radio Buttons to create URL from selection

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 Radio Buttons with a Select button - now i need to change the select button to which radio button is selected. 
For example html code:

```
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Orange"> Orange
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Apple""> Apple
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Mango"> Mango
 <button>Select</button>
```

I now would like to link my Select button to get an URL
This URL i think i'll have to place either in the html in some array of sort or read from a database.

Any advise on how to link the button and how to embed the URL would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for reading and commenting.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I didn't understand what u want

Comment: what does this phrase "i'll have to place either in the html in some array of sort or read from a database" mean ?!

Comment: I have tried using a Javascript Function to set the radio button to the url function radioLink(dest){

     if (document.radioLinks.Select)

            if (dest == 'Orange')
                location='orange.com'
            if (dest == 'Apple')
                location='apple.com'
            if (dest == 'Mango')
                location='mango.com'
     }

i am then not sure how to link my button to the radio buttons.

Comment: RomanPerekhrest - it just where i can read the specific URL from - this will not be used for oranges and apples as i have about 40 different URLS i need to be able to filter via the radio buttons that is selected by the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the url link as value of the radio button. Then on click of 
button get the value of checked radio button.

HTML

```
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Orange" name="myRadio" value="www.google.com"> Orange
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Apple" name="myRadio" value="www.mozilla.com"> Apple
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="Mango" name="myRadio" value="www.microsoft.com"> Mango
 <button onclick="navigateSite()">Select</button> //trigger navigateSite function
```

JS

```
function navigateSite(){
var getUrl = document.querySelector('input[name = "myRadio"]:checked').value
  console.log(getUrl);
  // location.href = getUrl // If you want to navigate to the site
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/huygd6s6/)

Comment: Thank you for this great answer - it seems to work fine but for some reason it places my current site url before the value from the radio button. Any idea on how i will be able to open the specific link or might there be an other problem with my specific site?

Answer (score 0):

```
<INPUT TYPE="radio" name="URL" id="Orange"> Orange
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="URL" id="Apple""> Apple
 <INPUT TYPE="radio" name="URL" id="Mango"> Mango
 <button onclick="getURL();">Select</button>

function getURL(){
var url = document.getElementsByName('URL');
var url_value;
for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++){
    if(url[i].checked){
        url_value = rates[i].value;
    }
}
location=url_value+'.com';
}
```